# Filter Array with multiple conditions in other array of options

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I am trying to filter an array passing dynamic filters for it but im kinda stuck.

```
const data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'john', location: 'NY', age: '50'},
    {id: 2, name: 'mj', location: 'LA', age: '41'},
    {id: 3, name: 'mike', location: 'LA', age: '50'},
    {id: 4, name: 'lebron', location: 'SF', age: '20'},
    {id: 5, name: 'mike', location: 'NY', age: '60'},
    {id: 6, name: 'john', location: 'MI', age: '30'},
    {id: 7, name: 'mj', location: 'NY', age: '53'}
]
```

and I have my filters

```
const filters = {
    name: ['mike', 'mj'],
    location: ['NY'],
    age: []
}
```

and I am trying to filter like this

```
const searchKeys = Object.values(selectedVehiclesFilters)
    .filter((xyz: any) => [...xyz])
    .flat() // <- this will return me ['mike', 'mj', 'NY']

    Object.entries(selectedVehiclesFilters).map(([key, values]) => {
      const keyName = stringToCamelCase(key)
      const abc = filteredRows.filter((vehicle: Data) => {
        return searchKeys.every((searchKey) =>
          vehicle[`${keyName as string}`].includes(searchKey),
        )
      })
    }),
```

Any tips how I should proceed?
The expected result would be around

```
abc: [
  { id: 7, name: 'mj', location: 'NY', age: '53'}, 
  { id: 5, name: 'mike', location: 'NY', age: '60'}
]
```

Comment: If the arrays represent values to be chosen, then `age: []` means no age should be chosen?

Comment: @ITgoldman it means the age[] will be ignored while filtering,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think flattening the filters is the right idea, because then you'll be mixing the different properties. Iterate over the filters object instead, and have the item pass the test if, for every filter property:

- the filter is empty, or
- the same property on the object being iterated over exists in the filter array

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'john', location: 'NY', age: '50'},
    {id: 2, name: 'mj', location: 'LA', age: '41'},
    {id: 3, name: 'mike', location: 'LA', age: '50'},
    {id: 4, name: 'lebron', location: 'SF', age: '20'},
    {id: 5, name: 'mike', location: 'NY', age: '60'},
    {id: 6, name: 'john', location: 'MI', age: '30'},
    {id: 7, name: 'mj', location: 'NY', age: '53'}
];
const filters = {
    name: ['mike', 'mj'],
    location: ['NY'],
    age: []
};

const filtered = data.filter(obj =>
  Object.entries(filters).every(([key, filterArr]) => (
    filterArr.length === 0 || filterArr.includes(obj[key])
  ))
);
console.log(filtered);
```